# Problemas con de react-chartjs-2 de React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts

a ver si hay alguien que me pueda ayudar.
Estoy haciendo un proyecto en react para mi empresa y me han pedido que introduzca gráficas, estoy utilizando react-chartjs-2 y tengo un problema con el parámetro option que introduzco, en resumen es, que no reconoce nada de lo que le paso en las opciones.
Dejo mi componente por aquí.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-2';

export const LineChart = () => {
  return <div>
      <Line 
        height={400}
        width={600}
        data={{
          labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
          datasets: [{
            label: "Active Users",
            borderColor: "#f96332",
            fill: false,
            backgroundColor: ['red'],
            data: [542, 480, 430, 550, 530, 453, 380, 434, 568, 610, 700, 630]
          }]
        }}
        options={{
          maintainAspectRatio: false,
          legend: {
            display: false
          },
          responsive: 1,
          scales: {
            xAxes: [{
              display: false
            }]
          }
        }}
      />
    </div>
}
```

Todo lo que se pasa por data, funciona correctamente, pero lo que pasa por options, solo me funciona `maintainAspectRatio: false`.

He instalado `npm install --save react-chartjs-2 chart.js`
y las versiones que se han instalado son las siguientes.

*este es el package.json*

```
{
  "name": "prduction_container",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.12.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "chart.js": "^3.3.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.6.0",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^3.0.3",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-search-field": "^1.2.1",
    "reactstrap": "^8.9.0",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Espero que podáis ayudarme, gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buscando en la [documentación](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html) encontré algunos ejemplos para configurar las opciones, podrías usar algo como esto:

```
options = {{
          plugins: {
              legend: {
                  display: false,
                
              },
              
          },
          responsive: true,
          scales: {
            x: {            
              display: false
            }
          }
      }}
```

En cuanto a responsive hay [consideraciones adicionales](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/responsive.html#important-note) te recomiendo que revises.

Y también dejan un   [codepen](https://codepen.io/chartjs/pen/YVWZbz) de ejemplo para el caso de responsive.

Espero te ayude la respuesta, saludos!

Comment: Me ha funcionado perfectamente, muchísimas gracias!